# script won't plot previous two day high and low lines

Tags: pine-script

This is a simple script that plots the previous two day high and low.

I don't get error when I run the script but script wont draw the lines.

CODE>>

//@version=5
indicator('prev2day', overlay=true, max_bars_back=2)

prev2dayhigh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high[2])

prev2daylow = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low[2])

plot(prev2dayhigh, title='Previous 2Day High', color=color.new(color.gray, 0), linewidth=1, style=plot.style_line, offset=-9999)

plot(prev2daylow, title='Previous 2Day Low',  color=color.new(color.gray, 0), linewidth=1, style=plot.style_line, offset=-9999)

output>>
[image: as you can see, it only outputs the labels but not the lines]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Due to the utilization of the `offset`, the plot function positions the point on the candle from the previous 9999 periods.

To extend the line, include `trackprice = true`.

see this in documentation for more information

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/Faq.html#plot-a-dynamic-horizontal-line